# How to remove the archiving in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-archive

Is there a way to get rid of archiving in Gmail? I don't want or need it.

Comment: What do you mean by getting rid of archiving?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot disable archive, but nothing is forcing you to use it. You can move all your messages from Archive to Inbox by these steps:

1. Click "All Mail" on the left to open all email messages.
2. Click checkbox to select all messages.
3. As step #2 will only select messages you are viewing, you have to click "Select all XXX conversations in All Mail" at the top of your message list so it selects everything in "All Mail".
4. Click "Move to Inbox" in the toolbar.

Now you have all your messages in Inbox and Archive is not used.

Comment: The problem is in new gmail GUI, The Archive button float on the mail title so It's very easy to wrong click it, and if you don't notice to click `undo`, you will waste your time to search how to unarchive your mail, **everytime** you do it because you can't remember how to unarchive your mail.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the archive button by:

click on the settings cog >> settings >> general >> hover actions

then change it from:

```
Enable hover actions - Quickly gain access to archive, delete, mark as read and snooze controls on hover
```

to
    Disable hover actions

(I kept accidentally archiving too, it was very annoying!)

Comment: That works well for the buttons Google added in the recent redesign, but the Asker seems to have been looking for a way to remove the functionality altogether.